# R - transforming 1 column into many

Tags: r

I have a data frame of all real estate transactions in France in 2015, however the dataframe was created with | separating the columns instead of ,. Which ends up creating one giant column.

How would you go on about, in R, to change that 1 column into many using the | as the character where you need to do the split.

I was thinking of doing a lot of mutates and/or transmute, but is there a more straight forward solution?

Here is an example of the data:

name of column --> Code service CH|Reference document|1 Articles CGI|2 Articles CGI|3 Articles CGI|4 Articles CGI|5 Articles CGI|No disposition|Date mutation|Nature mutation|Valeur fonciere|No voie|B/T/Q|Type de voie|Code voie|Voie|Code postal|Commune|Code departement|Code commune|Prefixe de section|Section|No plan|No Volume|1er lot|Surface Carrez du 1er lot|2eme lot|Surface Carrez du 2eme lot|3eme lot|Surface Carrez du 3eme lot|4eme lot|Surface Carrez du 4eme lot|5eme lot|Surface Carrez du 5eme lot|Nombre de lots|Code type local|Type local|Identifiant local|Surface reelle bati|Nombre pieces principales|Nature culture|Nature culture speciale|Surface terrain

data in column --> |||||||000001|01/07/2015|Vente|200000,00|17||LOT|A001|DU CLOS DES ACACIAS|1340|SAINT-DIDIER-D AUSSIAT|01|346||AI|326||||||||||||0|1|Maison||85|4|S||932

Comment: Can you please use `dput` to show example data as the formatting is not clear

Comment: It is not clear how you access the data, but if you are reading it from a flat data file, you may use a function where you can specify the character that shall be used to separate columns.

`readr::read_delim` is a great option. Here you can set `delim = "|"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your troubles.

The solution i came to was using the `sep = "|"` in `read.csv`

Answer (score 0):

If your column looks like that and your values look like that. You may use data.table's internal function:

**tstrsplit (transpose string split)**

```
bla <- data.table with

test|that|if|you|like
1:          apple|pinata
```

specific code:

**for values:**

```
tstrsplit(bla, "|", fixed=TRUE, keep=1:2)[] %>% as.data.table()
```

**gives:**

```
      V1     V2
1: apple pinata
```

**for columns:**

```
tstrsplit(names(bla), "|", fixed=TRUE, keep=1:4) %>% as.data.table()
```

**gives:**

```
     V1   V2 V3  V4
1: test that if you
```

keep in mind that the upper bound of the parameter *keep* is determined by your elements divided by the specific character, in your case |.

You could then rename the columns with the values with `setnames` Does this help you?